# JS autoscrolling to bottom isn't functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, php, autoscroll

This is kind of two questions within one but it is merely altering the same script so I hope nobody will mind, you'll see what I mean...

Within my messages feature I am displaying all messages using the script below and updating them every couple of seconds using `JS`:

```
<div class="list-group-message" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:385px;width:680px">    
 <div id="content">                            



<?
$res6=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_messages WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id' ORDER BY time_sent ASC");
while($row6=mysqli_fetch_array($res6))
{   
 $me_message = $row6['message'];
 $me_message_id = $row6['message_id'];
 $me_sender_id = $row6['sender_id'];
 $todaysdate = date('d/m/Y');
 $me_time_sent_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 $me_time_sent_date_and_time = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 $me_time_sent_time = date('H:i', strtotime($row6['time_sent']));
 if($todaysdate == $me_time_sent_date){
     $me_time = ''.$me_time_sent_time.'';
 } else {
    $me_time = ''.$me_time_sent_date.' '.$me_time_sent_time.''; 
 }


 $me_time_read = $row6['time_read'];
$res7=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_users WHERE user_id = '$me_sender_id'");
while($row7=mysqli_fetch_array($res7))
{   
 $me_first_name = $row7['first_name'];
 $me_last_name = $row7['last_name'];
  $me_display_img = $row7['display_img'];
}

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_messages SET time_read = NOW() WHERE message_id = '{$me_message_id}' AND time_read = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND conversation_id = '$co_conversation_id' AND sender_id != '$user_id'");
?>  




<div class="media" style="max-width: <? echo $screenwidth; ?>px;">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="userimg/<? echo $me_display_img; ?>" alt="user" width="64px" height="64px" hspace="10px" class="media-object" align="left">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" style="position: relative !important;">
    <div style="display:inline"><b><a href=""><? echo ''.$me_first_name.' '.$me_last_name.''; ?></a></b></div> <div align="right" style="float:right; display:inline"> <? echo $me_time; ?> </div><br>
    <? echo $me_message; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?
}
?>



</div>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" id="reply" name="reply" onsubmit="loadDoc()">
<div class="form-group">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="80" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Send a reply..."></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" id="conversation_id" name="conversation_id" value="<? echo $co_conversation_id; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" id="sarssystem" name="sarssystem" value="<? echo $sarssystem; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<? echo $user_id; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="right">

<div class="btn-group" align="left" style="float:left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="messages.php?convoid=<? echo $co_conversation_id; ?>&del=check">Delete Conversation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Visit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Report User</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Display Photo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Cancel</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Send Message</button>
</div>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").load(location.href+" #content","");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Right at the top there you can see my scroll bar feature:

```
<div class="list-group-message" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:385px;width:680px">
```

Which I am auto scrolling to the bottom using this code from my `assets/js` folder:

```
$(".list-group-message").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
  return false;
```

Which just about does the trick, although I am getting various errors with this system of auto scrolling.

- If conversation starts to build up too many messages (around 10ish) the auto scroll will only scroll to the middle of the conversation or such.
- If a reply is added, when the `DIV` is refreshed, the scroll bar stays at the previous message and won't automatically adjust to show this new message.
- Using a timing addition to automatically refresh the auto scroll, it begins only after the initial start time and not on page reload & still occurs issues with the first two problems & you cannot browse your messages as it will refresh and you'll loose your place every 5 seconds.

Is there a way I can combat these issues at all or is it something I will have to put up with while using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that might help you:

```
x = 0;  //horizontal coord
y = document.height; //vertical coord

setTimeout(function(){
  window.scroll(x,y);
},2000); //run every two seconds
```

I think this will help you accomplish what you need:
http://scripterlative.com/files/autodivscroll.htm

But if you like to write your own stuff, then seeing a code demo would be helpful.

You might like this too: http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/#